# how to determine whether I should go with singular or plural in the following sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number

I was just wondering what to choose between singular and plural in the following usage:

"Both functional and individual **distributions/distribution** of national income **are/is** addressed in the literature."

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot determine the number from the sentence fragment you provide.  But the ambiguity is only a true ambiguity if you can provide a full sentence in which the uncertainty is there.

Comment: @Tuffy Sorry I thought sentence fragment wouldn't be a problem to address my question because the segment has at least main subject and verb. I just edited the previous one with remaining missing part to make a complete sentence.

Comment: It's impossible to determine what you are trying to say.

Comment: @HotLicks, could you tell me why?

Comment: What are your arguments for singular and plural agreement for your example?

Comment: I had to check that both 'functional distribution' and 'personal distribution' were compound nouns rather than merely two-word collocations or free combinations. To help other non-specialists, I'd recommend 'Both the _functional distribution_ and the _individual distribution_ of national income are addressed in the literature.'

Comment: @Lawrence, my argument could be that since there are two types of distribution (functional and individual) and I want to avoid the repetition, it is better to be written: "Both functional and individual distributions of national income are addressed in the literature." But I am not sure this is grammatically valid statement.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, it sounds fair to me.

Comment: Your suggestion is grammatical. Mine also takes into account Gricean maxims /  pragmatics, in the belief that clarity and aid to comprehension trumps minor style considerations.

Comment: @joe That's reasonable. You'll need to check whether something is a compound word, in which case the repetition is needed for clarity. E.g. The sentence "They like ice cream and whipped cream." doesn't compress well into "They like ice and whipped cream." because "ice cream" is a compound word while "whipped cream" is either another compound word or a 'modifier + noun' structure.

Comment: @Lawrence, great! now I can confirm that my case is modifier.